# Solana Anchor Framework Installation Error: linking with 'cc' Failed

Tags: installation, frameworks, rust-cargo, anchor-solana

I have beed facing problem to install solana anchor framework.
rust version `rustc 1.65.0 (897e37553 2022-11-02)`
cargo version `cargo 1.65.0 (4bc8f24d3 2022-10-20)`

[image: This is the screen shot of the error]

if anybody know how to resolve this issue please reply
or tell me if i'm using a wrong version or wrong command

OS - Ubuntu 20.04

I have tried all the commands mentioned below but every command is throwing the same error.
`cargo install --git https://github.com/project-serum/anchor avm --locked --force`
`cargo install --git https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor avm --locked --force`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are missing some Linux Libraries,

Try installing these first

```bash
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install -y pkg-config build-essential libudev-dev libssl-dev
```